# Must diagonalization over a countable subset of the rationals produce an irrational?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Its easy enough to see why the classic diagonal argument proving the uncountability of the reals cannot similarly succeed when applied to the rationals. Fix an enumeration of the rationals, and take the diagonal real; it must be irrational, since if its rational we just look at where the diagonal intersects itself horizontally, and at that digit it must not have been changed.

Note that this simple argument seems to require that the fixed enumeration of the rationals we're diagonalizing against not omit any rational (in particular, the fact that it contained the diagonal seems crucial). But we can just as easily take the diagonal of (some enumeration of) a countable proper subset of the rationals.

1. Suppose we diagonalize over a fixed enumeration of only some countable proper subset of the rationals. Must the resulting number be irrational?
2. If 1) holds, is there any equally easy way of seeing this?

Comment: #1 -- The resulting number does not have to be irrational. Diagonalize over the subset of rationals that have a decimal expansion consisting of only $0$'s and $3$'s by choosing the $n$'th digit of the resulting number to be $5.$ Then the resulting number is the rational number $5/11.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro You mean 5/9.

Comment: Great, thanks. I think I'm curious about some sharper versions of the question now but I'll have to think about it some more.

Comment: @bof: Just seeing if anyone was paying attention :)